# How to detect mouseOver events on an element at the very left edge of a page in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I have a pop out menu that is triggered from a mouse over event on an element that is on the left edge of the page. So when the mouse hits the far left of the page (and typically for a maximised browser window this is also the edge of the screen) the menu pops open.

It works in Firefox, Chrome, IE6, IE9 but in IE8 there appears to be a 2 pixel "edge" around the html page when the window in maximised or windowed. If the window is full screen (F11) then there is no 2 pixel edge. The 2 pixel border / edge doesn't detect mouseOver / onClick events for elements that are against the left edge of the page.

Here's a image with the red arrows pointing to the 2 pixel edge:

[image]

So is there are way to work around this or is it an unavoidable IE8 quirk?

Answer (score 0):

Well after more research, I think that's just the way IE8 is. The main workaround is to make the "trigger" mouse over area large enough to be clearly visible so it will be hard for users not to mouse over it on the way to the edge of the screen. Some of my clients' upgrade paths to IE9 will be well into 2012 so I'll just have to live with this workaround.